# how to render html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

I have a javascript engine(using jquery) that needs to render a html which comes as a output from a third party server (REST API). The response contains plain text and occasional html elements like `<b>, <p> <br>` etc which I want to render as html output. (and not literally as `<b>, <p>` etc)

Is there a way ?

Here is what I am doing - in pseudo code. Note : I am using [blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates) javascript template to generate code.

```
jQuery.get({
    url: 'someRESTfulURL/id',
    method: 'get',
    success: function(resp) {
      //resp contains html elements like <b> etc
      var data = {title: resp.title, content: resp.content};
      $("#maindiv").html(tmpl("text-tmpl", data)); 
    }
});

<script type="text/x-tmpl" id="text-tmpl">
    <h3>{%=o.title%}</h3>
    <p>{%=o.content%}</p>
</script>

<html><body><div id='maindiv'></div></body></html>
```

The [javascript template](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates/blob/master/js/tmpl.js) is encoding the html characters and hence the problem. Is there a way I can use this template and still render the html chars.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Have you tried $('#yourelement').html(data); ??

Comment: Yes, I have. BUt I think the problem lies somewhere, as far as I can tell after digging. Probably lies with the template I am using.

Comment: @Dilpa If you still got that issue, you should have a look at the answer I gave. It addresses the JS templating you are doing, whereas the other hints didn't really take the template engine you are using into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prevent the escaping of HTML special characters. Try this:

```
<script type="text/x-tmpl" id="text-tmpl">
    <h3>{%#o.title%}</h3>
    <p>{%#o.content%}</p>
</script>
```

The difference is just the '#' instead of the '='.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do this with jQuery:

1. The first is when you have the response data already, then you can put it into an element like this:

   ```
   $("#myElement").html(myData);
   ```
2. The second is that you could load the data directly into the element:

   ```
   $("#myElement").load("http://myurlgoeshere.com/webservice");
   ```